# Parallel programming languages which look deterministic?

Tags: programming-languages

Are there any programming languages where the system parallelizes the program without any noticeable differences for the programmer?

That is, the programmer writes a linear, deterministic program, without any additional tags or meta-data, and the underlying system parallelizes all of the work.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "linear"?

Comment: If you follow the execution pattern, you get a straight line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

haskell has a host of [parallelism and concurrency features](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.10.3/html/users_guide/lang-parallel.html). [STM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory) has been popularized and much-discussed since being implemented by haskell. you might also like Go, it has a [channel feature](http://www.re-cycledair.com/playing-with-go-channels-and-go-routines) that may be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

[Fortress](http://projectfortress.sun.com/Projects/Community) kind of does this, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean procedural, and not deterministic. In C#, there is some work underway to enable an asynchronous programming model which more closely models the procedural programming approaches we're used to. See Jeffrey Richter's IAsyncResult and the new [Async CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/async.aspx) from Microsoft.

F# and other functional languages have had comprehensive asynchrony models for some time.  Ultimately you still have to adhere to the baisc tenets of concurrency: isolation, immutability, and synchronization (usually in that order of resort). I recommend the several whitepapers at the above site for a glimpse of how Concurrency should be more accessible--at least in C#--in the near future.

Comment: No, I specifically am looking for models which allow the programmer to write programs which read as if they are linear and deterministic, but contain components which parallelize and execute the code in a non-deterministic fashion. For example, I might write for (each i in array) { i blink red once;}; for (each i in array) { i blink green once;}; and the underlying system may have some i's having blinked red and green before others, and moved on, some never blink at all and not moved on, and some never blinking and moving on anyways.